# Button in iframe to make div display in parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

So i have a button in my iframe to open a div on the same page:

```
<li>
    <input type='button' id='hideshow2' class='radiobutton' value='Core' onclick="showDiv('#content2')">
</li>

<div id='content2' class="content2">
</div>
```

with the javascript

```
<script type='text/javascript'>     
function showDiv() {
   document.getElementById('content2').style.display = "block";
}
</script>
```

which works perfectly fine, however i'm trying to get it so the button can be inside an iframe which when pressed activates the div show on parent page.

Is this possible ? iv'e tried Googling loads of things but i'm not even 100% sure what to Google

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it should be:

window.parent.document.getElementById('content2').style.display = "block";

Answer (score 0):

You can position the button over the iframe however, you can't display it in the iframe unless its part of the original file that is being displayed.

You can position the button with `z-index` and `position: relative`.